# ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray' [New Edit this are good]

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, numpy

I have this error and I do not know how to fix it I have tried many meneras and I do not know how I created new post because the other was badly

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 9, in <module>
    from layer import MacLayer
  File "/root/MacBot/layer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app import main
  File "/root/MacBot/app/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from app.yesno.yesno import YesNo
  File "/root/MacBot/app/yesno/yesno.py", line 2, in <module>
    import moviepy.editor as mp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/moviepy-0.2.2.11-py3.5.egg/moviepy/editor.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/moviepy-0.2.2.11-py3.5.egg/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 3, in <module>
    from moviepy.video.VideoClip import VideoClip
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/moviepy-0.2.2.11-py3.5.egg/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 15, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: click in the link to see the error

Comment: Yes, but it would be helpful to see the actual code as well

Comment: @Endermrn No. Do **not** post links to code or errors. Copy and paste the relevant text *into your question*.

Comment: What code do you mean?

Comment: @Endermrn please read the tutorial on [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, I just edited the post looking at it now

Comment: @back2basics post edited

Comment: @brandon-minnick post edited

Comment: @juanpa-arrivillaga post edited

Comment: @kaipatel post edited

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to use anaconda available from [continuum.io/downloads](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)
then you aren't messing with compiling this yourself.

Comment: i install anaconda and try to install a setup and get this error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: i'm assuming you have linux then.  do you have gcc installed?

Comment: I get quite a bit of python and linux over all but this is the first time I get these python errors and I can not fix

Comment: Are you having unrelated issues with getting to files? (file system crashing?) easy fix is try a restart.

Comment: this error i have in a new server and yes i try to restart

Comment: Do you have a 64 bit server?

Comment: nope. But I couldn't do that right now if I wanted.

Comment: are you trying to run the installer as root?  (install as a user)

Comment: install it into the home directory of a user other than root.  as a user of the system not root

Comment: Running python-axolotl-curve25519-0.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-1r716v87/python-axolotl-curve25519-0.1/egg-dist-tmp-ihtucbwz
curve25519module.c:3:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: python.h is a header file in python-dev try "sudo apt-get install python-dev"